# Mysql - JSON_CONTAINS find within array

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have json column with following data:

```
[{"option_id": 1, "category_id": 1}, {"option_id": 2, "category_id": 2}]
```

I am trying to find records with **option_id = 1**

This is query I am trying:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `complaint_forms` 
where json_contains(`outcome_options`, '1', '$."option_id"')
```

Count is 0. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$.option_id` requires `option_id` to be a key of the top-level object, not a nested object in an array.

Comment: Is there a way to search with this structure or I have to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to specify the candidate as an object with the desired attribute and value, not just the value, and not specify a path:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `complaint_forms` 
where json_contains(`outcome_options`, '{"option_id":1}')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=570b98bcc88e58746da51018103b762c)